# How can I add cache control in Flask when I'm rendering a template?

Tags: python, flask

I read this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115561/1765681 . It works but it make global. So my admin page get cached. And I don't want that.

For example. If I want to set cache control only to this:

```
@app.route('/')
def list_posts():
    entries = db_session.query(Entry).order_by(desc(Entry.id)).limit(5)
    return render_template('list.html', entries=entries)
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the response from render_template, and then adjust it as necessary.

Like this:

```
#UNTESTED
@app.route('/')
def list_posts():
    entries = db_session.query(Entry).order_by(desc(Entry.id)).limit(5)
    resp = make_response(render_template('list.html', entries=entries))
    resp.cache_control.max_age = 300
    return resp
```

References:

- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#cookies
- http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#about-responses
- [Using Flask, how do I modify the Cache-Control header for ALL output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112316/using-flask-how-do-i-modify-the-cache-control-header-for-all-output/23115561#23115561)

Comment: cloudfare don't cache it. You know why?

Comment: Nope, but that sounds like a different question.

Comment: It seems that is because I'm using flask login, and by default it sets a cookie. And Cloudfare do not cache when a cookie is present.