# Why HTML file is displaying old image if I replace the file with same old name in directory?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm creating webapp by using Flask on backend and HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 4 on frontend and havenot using a single line of code of javascript. My flask app code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But, the issue is when I add an image in HTML code it works completely fine. But if I replace the file in directory with same name but when I preview it in browser while coding it shows the old picture. I'm using Bootstrp 4.6

The image code inside a simple div is:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="/static/about.svg" alt="Students">
```

Comment: Clearing your cache might help.

Answer (score 1):

That because of your local browser cache (see in the network panel of our browser dev tools : image requests don't have a 200 http status code). You should want to [disable it during development](https://nicholasbering.ca/tools/2016/10/09/devtools-disable-caching/).

But you must handle it in production too, with plugins like [Flask-caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or with [cache control mecanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45583828/python-flask-not-updating-images).

Answer (score 0):

In a youtube tutorial, I get to know that by refreshing page while pressing "Ctrl-key" clears the cache. And it worked for me.

Comment: thats the manual way to clear local cache :)