# Website caching- browser caches website pages/js and avoid user to see website updates

Tags: javascript, html, browser-cache

I have a website that used javascript and HTML pages. When I update any HTML/javascript, the user doesn't see the change unless he deleted all his cookies, browser cache, and history.

I tried adding the following in the HTML Head section. But it doesn't help.
Also, I tried adding "?v=1" for each javascript include. But it doesn't help either.

```
<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"/>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
```

What can be done so the browser won't save website cache etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You should try setting the [`cache-control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) headers on your server for your HTML file:

`Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"`

Example article for Apache: [Proper cache busting for index.html (Apache)](https://www.competa.com/blog/proper-cache-busting-index-html-apache/). Different servers have different ways of setting these headers, but the HTTP headers are the same for all.

Once that is done, you should still change the v= query param on your internal JS/CSS files, to be sure you bust (or use!) their cached version when required.

Comment: what about prevent html pages from caching?

Comment: These headers are for any HTTP response from your server. See [setHeader](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value) for node.js. [This SO q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112316/using-flask-how-do-i-modify-the-cache-control-header-for-all-output) for Flask. etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should add something unique to the end of the url you are trying to get the assets from

```
<script src="test.js?version=1"></script>
```

This is the most reliable way of doing that.

I would maintain a version number somewhere and get JS to append it to the url if I have so many assets to load.

Here is some help -

https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/front-end-dev/what-is-cache-busting/

And please see this question too -

[How to prevent caching of my Javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413234/how-to-prevent-caching-of-my-javascript-file)

Comment: what about prevent html pages from caching?