# Flask login vs. Apache caching

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi, flask-session

I'm a novice web developer, but experienced python programmer, and Apache dolt.  Recently, I've been tinkering with hosting a small website and learning my way through some hosting issues, Flask, html templates, etc.

I've followed several Flask tutorials about controlling access to pages with `@login_required` decorators on access-controlled endpoints and using `session` to store a logged in k-v pair.  This all works perfectly when running locally on Flask's development server on my local machine.  However, when I push this onto my hosting service, I'm getting what I believe is cached behavior to many of the access-controlled endpoints and I'm able to see them after logging out (and checking the session data to ensure the key is removed).

Some specifics...

- Using `flask` with `session` for the login info, *not* flask-login.
- Hosting on a managed VPS that is using Phusion Passenger as a WSGI
  interface to Apache
- I have no config files in use for Apache...just defaults right now.
- Website is very low traffic...  Prolly just me & the bots right now.  :)

My `passenger_wsgi` file:

```
import sys, os
from datetime import timedelta
INTERP = "/home/<website>/venv1/bin/python3"
#INTERP is present twice so that the new Python interpreter knows the actual executable path
if sys.executable != INTERP: os.execl(INTERP, INTERP, *sys.argv)

# def application(environ, start_response):
#     start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
#     return ["Hello, world!"]

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from app import app as application
```

After I login, things work as expected.  After logout, I can still hit the endpoints that are supposed to be access-controlled and I repeatedly see this "evidence" when I inspect the network traffic in my browser:

```
Summary
URL: https://<website>/<endpoint>  <---- an endpoint covered by @login_required
Status: 200
Source: Memory Cache

Request
No request, served from the memory cache.

Response
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 22 Dec 2021 17:14:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 22 Dec 2021 17:04:00 GMT
Content-Length: 23
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Vary: User-Agent
Status: 200 OK
x-powered-by: Phusion Passenger 5.0.30
Server: Apache
```

So my questions are these...

1. Is my diagnosis correct that this is Apache caching at work?  (Evidence looks compelling...  :) )
2. I'd rather not (at this time) invest effort into moving to `flask-login` unless that is curative.
3. Is there a simple way to control this behavior without becoming an expert in apache or Passenger config files or such?  I don't mind just turning caching off if that is doable for this low-traffic site, but I'd be interested in what a *good solution* looks like to in order to educate myself on either controlling the caching or telling apache somehow (?) which endpoints are access controlled, etc.

I humbly submit my question to the folks who deal with these stacks!

Comment: Just confirming you pop the k-v out of the session collection when the user logs out? Another way to get around this is to clear the session prior to the user logging in.

Comment: Looks like you are getting the response from your browser cache. To confirm try logout, clean your browser cache and try go to the url

Comment: Have you tried adding no cache headers to response of those specific routes ?
Waiting for a reply..

Comment: @Dev, did that yesterday and I think we are cured.  :).  I thought the caching was occurring server side, but I think the true issue was browser caching.  I sprinkled `flask` `response` all over the place with no-cache headers added, and we are working well now!  Good eye!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the caching. Usually `response.cache_control` is set in an `after_request`. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115561/5378816 - but to disable caching use other cache control settings: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18148884/5378816

Comment: AirSquid , just a suggestion for code, instead of adding no cache headers all over the code, you can add it to @login_required decorator , so that only restricted routes can be kept away from caching.

Comment: These are great pointers.  Thank you both.

Comment: If your application's performance would not be degraded if not cached, how about you disable it as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34066804/disabling-caching-in-flask). This way, the request has to be live every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 5.0, passenger will "helpfully" add cache-control headers to responses it deems 'cachable'.

In order to stop this, your application [should add the header `Cache-Control: no-store`](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/03/31/passenger-5-0-6/#turbocachevsnocachefixed).

To do this globally in Flask as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331139/5747944):

```py
@app.after_request
def add_header(response):
    # response.cache_control.no_store = True
    if 'Cache-Control' not in response.headers:
        response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store'
    return response
```

If you want to be more discriminating and only want to do this for routes which require a login, you could make your own extension to the `login_required` decorator to do this for your routes which require logins (or a separate decorator entirely)

```py
from flask import make_response
from flask_login import login_required as _login_required

def login_required(f):
    # apply the usual login_required decorator
    decorated = _login_required(f)
    def cache_no_store_login_required_view(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = make_response(decorated(*args, **kwargs))
        # add the cache-control header to the response
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store'
        return resp
    return cache_no_store_login_required_view
```

Or as a separate decorator to set no-store...

```py
from functools import wraps
def cache_no_store(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
        resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
        resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-store'

@app.route('/protected')
@cache_no_store
@login_required
def my_route():
    # ...
```

Comment: The comments above were on the mark, but this is a good comprehensive explanation. Thanks