# Flask, possible to cache images

Tags: html, image, flask

I'd like to be able to save images and not have them reload on every page change.

I can probably get away with using localstorage, but this seems like something which should be handled by the browser and server without the need for new code.

Is there an obvious thing I am missing?

I thought of .htaccess but that's related to apache which I am not using.

I see

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
```

But I have no idea how to change request headers for static content.

Comment: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356188/flask-static-file-cache-control) - [webassets in Flask](https://flask-assets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask-assets)

Comment: Thanks! I actually solved this in a different way! Thanks for showing me that!

Answer (score 0):

Edited the headers directly by overriding the static folder:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder=None)
@app.route('/static/<path:filename>')
def static(filename):
    resp = make_response(send_from_directory('static/', filename))
    resp.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age'
    return resp
```

worked out nicely!